# AWS Lambda export Api Gatewat backup to S3

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, boto3

I am trying to configure an lambda function which will export Api backup to S3. But when i try to get an ordinary swagger backup through lambda using this script-

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('apigateway')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = client.get_export(
        restApiId='xtmeuujbycids',
        stageName='test',
        exportType='swagger',
        parameters={
            extensions: 'authorizers'
        },
        accepts='application/json'
        )
```

I am getting this error-
[ERROR] NameError: name 'extensions' is not defined

Please help to resolve this issues.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check if the documentation has been explicitly published, and if it has been deployed to a stage before it available in the export.

Comment: yes, it is already in the staging. I used this API in my local server using user-based auth. and it worked. But in lambda, it failed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in:

```
parameters={
    extensions: 'authorizers'
        }
```

You're passing a dictionary, which is ok, but the key should be a string. Since you don't have quotes around `extensions`, Python is trying to resolve it as a variable with the name `extensions` which doesn't exist in your code, and so it gives the `NameError`